# Select Query in sql with testing on each row

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures

i have the following query:

```
SELECT favorite_id,MO,name,b.image_id,image_path FROM buddies b,images i where reg_id=@regID and b.image_id=i.image_id
```

the field b.image_id in buddies should b tested before getting the image_path from the table images... if the image_id is 0 i have to the the image_id from a table registration and the get the image_path from the table image and if the image_id is different than 0 i directly get the image_id from the table images... so when selecting the favorite_id and the image_id from table buddies i need to loop on this table for every row and test the image_id

can anyone help me?

Comment: You mentioned registration table but it is not part of the query. Your description is quiet confusing. And I think it's best to show the tables and its structure. By the way you have mysql and then sqlserver as part of your tags, which one is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT favorite_id,MO,name,
b.image_id,
image_path = case when b.image_id ='0' then i1.image_path else i.image_path end

FROM buddies b, registration r 
left join images i  on b.image_id=i.image_id
left join images i1 on r.image_id=i1.image_id
where b.reg_id=@regID and  r.reg_id=@regID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT favorite_id,MO,name,b.image_id,
       case b.image_id when 0 then i.image_path else b.image_path end as image_path
  FROM buddies b,images i 
  where reg_id=@regID and b.image_id=i.image_id
```

Smth like that...

If you need additional conditional select -- then it's here: [SELECT CASE WHEN THEN (SELECT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885912/select-case-when-then-select)

Comment: when 0 i need to write another select... how can i do that?

Comment: In MS SQL I usualy make additional join (left join) and then use "case" as in above. You want something like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885912/select-case-when-then-select ?