# select statement in case statement sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

how do I execute sql statement in between case when statement ?

I am trying to execute following query and getting error :

```
select *, 
case when 'trans_type' <> 'Stock' then 
lname else (select item_name from trans_i where id = a.id limit 0,1) end as lname
from 'transaction' as a
```

database is MySql

error :

```
Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select item_name from trans_i limit 0,1
```

ps : I am using transaction as table name for demo purpose only, its not 'transaction' in my real database.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: `transaction` is a reserved word.  Try wrapping it in backticks: ``...FROM `transaction` ``.

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885912/select-case-when-then-select

Comment: @RocketHazmat : i am using transaction for demo purposes only. its not my real table name.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be correct statement.

```
select *, 
(case when trans_type <> 'Stock' then 
a.lname else (select item_name from trans_i ti where ti.id = a.id limit 0, 1)
end) as 'lname' from transaction as `a`
```