# How the write the query to get the special price if available

Tags: mysql

I have a table structure as follows:

```
-- 1 price type.

   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `price_type` (
     `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `price_type` (`id`, `type`) VALUES
(1, 'Normal price'),
(2, 'Special price');

-- 2 Products

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

INSERT INTO `product` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Tshirt'),
(2, 'Shirt'),
(3, 'Pants'),
(4, 'Pull over');

-- 3 Product price

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_price` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` float NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `end_date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

INSERT INTO `product_price` (`id`, `product_id`, `price_type_id`, `price`, `start_date`, `end_date`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 300, '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00'),
(2, 2, 1, 500, '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00'),
(3, 3, 1, 400, '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00'),
(4, 3, 2, 150, '2015-08-01', '2015-11-02'),
(5, 4, 1, 600, '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00');
```

Expected result (special period of time):
[image]

Products(product) prices are stored in different table (product_price) with different price types (price_type) ids.

In this case the product Pants have special price 150.00 in between 2015-08-01 and 2015-11-02. So it should show the special price not the normal price 400.00

How can I write the query for it?

Comment: try reading about joins and how to use them

Comment: The date is not relevant to the operation that you want. This is like @satya  said a simple JOIN operation. Try to read about it, then show us what you tried THEN you update your question with your sql. SO is not a home work service.

Comment: check the answers of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885912/select-case-when-then-select

Comment: Thank you guys for the reply. I know JOIN basics but this conditions seems difficult for me. Its really nice to see the approaches of different people for the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the price table twice, once to get the normal price and once (left joined) for the special price, if there is any that is valid for today.

In the field list, you can use `coalesce` to get the special price, falling back to the normal price. This way, you can easily return the current price from the query regardless of which type it is:

```
select  p.id as product_id,
        p.name,
        np.price as normal_price,
        sp.price as special_price,
        sp.end_date as special_price_end_date,

        coalesce(sp.price, np.price) as current_price
from  product p
inner join product_price np 
      on np.product_id = p.id
         and np.price_type_id = 1
left  join product_price sp 
      on sp.product_id = p.id
         and sp.price_type_id = 2
         and CURRENT_DATE() between sp.start_date and sp.end_date
```

Comment: Trol, Thank you very much! it gives the result as I expected. To ask the question I have simplified the table structure. I hope it will work for my actual need.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
SELECT pp.id, p.name, pp.price, pp.start_date, pp.end_date FROM product_price pp
INNER JOIN product p
ON pp.product_id=p.id
WHERE 
(pp.start_date < '2015-08-01' AND pp.end_date > '2015-08-01')
OR (pp.start_date IS NULL AND pp.end_date IS NULL)
GROUP BY p.name
ORDER BY pp.price_type_id DESC
```

Comment: thank you very much for your replay and this solution works as I needed. When I executed the code for my actual issue Golez Trols's solution works well.